# Xcopy copies contents of file but leaves the directory out

Tags: windows-xp, xcopy

Need help for xcopy command,

I have a directory structure and wanted to copy few contents of this.
Iam using xcopy for the same but having trouble. My directory structure is below.

```
  I:\Foo\             
      |
      |--coo-->c1-->c2
      |--goo-->g1-->g2
      |--boo-->b1-->b2
      |--fow-->f1-->f2
```

which in turn contains subfolders and also files.
I want to copy coo and all its subfolder to another location, my xcopy command for the same is,

xcopy I:\Foo\coo e:\temp /e/c/t/h/r/y /s

executing this command copies folders and subfolders from c1-->c2 but folder coo is missing.

-regards,
Manju

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xcopy I:\Foo\coo e:\temp` copies the contents of coo into temp. If you want to copy coo into e:\temp\coo, you want `xcopy I:\Foo\coo e:\temp\coo` (assuming temp already exists).

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a user error. xcopy supports a source, a destination, some flags, and an exclude list.

When you use `xcopy I:\foo\coo e:\temp`, you say that the contents INSIDE the source(I:\foo\coo) should be equal to the contents INSIDE the destination (e:\temp). So you need to use something like:

```
xcopy I:\foo\coo e:\temp\coo
```

to make it include the `coo` folder.

Comment: Hi Graimer, Thanks for the response. I agree your solution and also the one above this from SirPentor.